# How to add multiple condition with wherePivot belongsToMany relation

Tags: laravel

I am working with Laravel 7. I have 3 tables

table_1

- id

table_1_table_2

- id_table_1 (fk to table_1)
- id_table_2 (fk to table_2)
- value (string)
- hidden (bool)

table_2

- id

So what i want is to get all entries in table that's connected to my Object in table_1.

So i did this :

```
public function table2() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(table_2,'table_1_table_2','id_table_1','id_table2')->withPivot(['value','hidden']);
}
```

Works great. Now I want only those who are not hidden. So i did

```
public function table2NotHidden() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(table_2,'table_1_table_2','id_table_1','id_table2')->wherePivot('hidden',0)->withPivot(['value','hidden']);
}
```

Works great Expect I need them where `hidden == 0` but also if `hidden == null`

And I tried several things like `->where(function($query){...})` `->wherePivot(function($query){...})` etc... but nothing seems to work.

Comment: did you try `wherePivotIn`? `wherePivotIn('hidden',[0,null]);` check here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: I tried that @DilipHirapara . Looked like (and still does) the perfect way to do it. But it doesn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try nested where:

```
 public function table2NotHidden() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('table_2','table_1_table_2','id_table_1','id_table2')->
        where(function($query){ $query->wherePivot('hidden',0)->orWherePivot('hidden',null);
        });
}
```

or you can use @Dilip Hirapara solution:

```
->wherePivotIn('hidden', [0, null]);


return $this->belongsToMany(table_2,'table_1_table_2','id_table_1','id_table2')->where(function ($q) {
                    $q->orWhereNull('table_1_table_2.hidden')
                      ->orWhere('table_1_table_2.hidden',0);
                })
```

Comment: I am not sure about `wherePivotIn` works with `null`. but I never seen `orWherePivot` before.

Comment: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::orWherePivot()").

Comment: Yes, becuase there is no method such as `orWherePivot`

Comment: orWherePivot seems to works fine when not in a subquery

Comment: strange enough: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_orWherePivot

Comment: I'm on laravel 7

Comment: even for laravel 7:https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.html#method_orWherePivot

Comment: I have edited the answer, check the solution if it works!

Comment: thank you @DilipHirapara now I got the idea.

Comment: Works like a charm @DilipHirapara . Seems really strange to have to write it like this. But if it works, it works thank you